# If (Integer Console.Readline "" or null) doesn't work

Tags: c#

I can't figure out after searching and searching (you know how it goes) why this code doesn't work.

I just want it to work like this

```
if (Nummer == "") {
    Console.WriteLine("0");
}
```

That's it, and it doesn't work. I have been searching for an hour and a half. Can't understand why there is a simple basic explanation. I only found how to fix it with a string or something, then I tried to convert it and it still didn't work. Can someone help me please?

I appreciate your patience for my limited knowledge. Thanks for your time

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool herhaal = true;

    do
    {                
        Console.Write("Geef een getal : ");
        int Nummer = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());           

        if (Console.ReadLine() == "" && Console.ReadLine() == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0");
        }

        double kw = Math.Pow(Nummer, 2);

        Console.WriteLine("Kwadraat van {0} is: {1}", Nummer, kw + Environment.NewLine);
    } while (herhaal);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `ReadLine()` three times.  That reads three lines.

Comment: Not sure, but something you may want to try is `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nummer)){Console.WriteLine("0");}`  And @SLaks is right, which could also be causing your issue(s).

Comment: why not just put `I just want it to work like this` example into your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Nummer;
    bool herhaal = true;
    do
    {                
        Console.Write("Geef een getal : ");          
        //only read from the Console ONCE per loop iteration, and always read to a string first
        string input = Console.ReadLine(); 

        //TryParse better than Convert for converting strings to integers
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out Nummer))        
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0");
        }
        else  //only do the second part if the conversion worked
        {
            double kw = Math.Pow(Nummer, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Kwadraat van {0} is: {1}\n", Nummer, kw);
        }

    } while (herhaal);
}
```

To do this from a WinForms app, as attempted in the comments:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double aantalgroep;
    if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep))        
    {
        textBox1.Text = "0";
    }
    else 
    {
        double kw = Math.Pow(aantalgroep, 2);
        textBox1.Text = String.Format("Kwadraat van {0} is: {1}", aantalgroep, kw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. And if i am not in the console, just in the forms application is that syntax the same? Because i am now busy with that `aantalgroep = double.Parse(textBox1.Text); if (aantalgroep == null)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "0";
                }`Because that doesn't work, i am going to try how you did it here to my other code.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. In a forms application there's no such thing as a `Console` object, and you **NEVER** write `while(true)` loop. Instead, you have a button with `click` event handler, and you have a textbox where you check the `Text` property. Also, primitive types like `int` and `double` will not ever be null. You should still use `TryParse()` like I showed in this answer, and check the result of that function.

Answer (score 1):

The `Console.ReadLine()` method 'reads' one line of user input, and stores in whatever the variable you assign it to. Here's [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So, your following line of code reads the number you inputs and stores in `Nummer`.

```
int Nummer = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
```

But then you go on and do two more `Console.ReadLine()` method calls in your `if` statement, so what the `if` statement really does is try to read from the console two more times, and see if the first read is `""` **and** if the second read is `null`, which is not your desired behavior.

What you want to do is read once, and compare whatever you read. Going by your code it looks like you want to output the square of the number entered by the user, so you probably should check for more than just `Nummer == ""`, since if the user entered an alphabet character, that would also result in an error. So using `int.TryPrase()` is a better option for you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool herhaal = true;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Geef een getal : ");
        string Nummer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(Nummer, out int result))
        {
            double kw = Math.Pow(result, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Kwadraat van {0} is: {1}", Nummer, kw + Environment.NewLine);
            herhaal = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0");
        }

    } while (herhaal);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. And if i am not in the console, just in the forms application is that syntax the same? Because i am now busy with that `aantalgroep = double.Parse(textBox1.Text); if (aantalgroep == null) { textBox1.Text = "0"; }`Because that doesn't work, i am going to try how you did it here to my other code.

Comment: Don't use `double.Parse()`, use `double.TryPrase()` instead. The latter tries to convert the `string` to `double`, and returns `true` if successful and `false` if unsuccessful. Look up C# documentation for the two method definitions. So you can simply check the output of `double.TryParse()` and if `true`, do whatever you want with the value and if `false`, you can set `textBox1.Text = "0"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to clear up. I change it to TryParse and in the if statement i can use ‘(aantalgroep == false) ??? Or do you just mean i can then use ‘(aantalgroep == “”)’ Sorry for not checking on my laptop but i woke up in the middle of the night and i am using my phone. Just to know this for sure because i have been losing alot of hours to figure simple things out

Comment: First of all you should check it on your PC. Next, you should probably go back to drawing board and learn about data types. The type of comparisons you can do on a variable depends on its type; if it's a `boolean` you can do a `true/false` comparison, and if it's a `string` you can do a string comparison, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the C# Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), `Console.ReadLine` does the following

> Reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream.

This means that every time you call `Console.ReadLine`, a new line will be read from the console. From what I can see in your code, this isn't the behavior that you want. To fix your problem, you should store the result of `Console.ReadLine` in a variable and use that variable instead of the ReadLine method.